# Changing Counter target according to input

Tags: verilog, fpga, spartan

I'm working on a project for a digital design course, and I have to play musical notes using frequencies in my project. I must say I'm fairly inexperienced in verilog (have to use verilog for the project). I researched a bit regarding the topic and found ([here](http://www.fpga4fun.com/MusicBox2.html)) the following code snippet:

```
    module music(clk, speaker);
    input clk;
    output speaker;
    parameter clkdivider = 25000000/440/2;

    reg [14:0] counter;
    always @(posedge clk) if(counter==0) counter <= clkdivider-1; else counter <= counter-1;

    reg speaker;
    always @(posedge clk) if(counter==0) speaker <= ~speaker;
    endmodule
```

In this code the clock is 25MHz and the frequency of the output is 440, what I want to do is change the frequency of the output according to user input, so I assume I just have to change the value the counter counts to. How can I neatly add that to the code so it should work ?

Comment: Do you want to be able to play one note at a time or multiple notes at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, I've set-up an environment for you.
You must add you're logic to make the correct functionality (homework)
especially in counter register where in you have to calculate the 
required frequency.

```
          // change logic here (to add userinput)
            counter <= clkdivider-1;
```

Since you want to change the frequency of the output according to user input,
you should add an input port to the `music` module.

```
module music(clk, reset, userinput, valid, speaker);
    input clk, valid, reset;
    input [7:0] userinput;
    output speaker;
```

`userinput` is 8 bits but you can change this based from your requirements.
Take note that a `valid` signal is also needed for handshaking with the other
modules.

Reset is also added to clear your `music` module.

Here is your testbench

```
module testmusic;
reg clk;
reg [7:0] userinput;
wire speaker;
reg valid;
 reg reset;


initial begin
  forever begin
    #1 clk = !clk;
  end
end

initial begin
  clk = 0;
  userinput = 0;
  valid = 0;
  @(posedge clk);
  $monitor("userinput: %0h valid: %0h speaker: %0h\n", userinput, valid, speaker);
end


 task resetdut;
   reset = 0;

   repeat (3) begin
    @(posedge clk);
   end

   reset <= 1;

   repeat (3) begin
    @(posedge clk);
   end

   reset <= 0;
 endtask

 music dut(clk, reset, userinput, valid, speaker);

 initial begin
   #10000; $finish;
 end

 // perform our testing here
 initial begin
   // perform reset to initialize our dut
   resetdut;
   testuserinput;
 end

 task testuserinput;
   @(posedge clk);
   userinput <= 8'hF; // insert user input here
   valid <= 1;
   @(posedge clk);
   userinput <= 0;
   valid <= 0;
   @(posedge clk);
 endtask


endmodule
```

Here is your RTL code that you need to fix.

```
module music(clk, reset, userinput, valid, speaker);
    input clk, valid, reset;
    input [7:0] userinput;
    output speaker;
    parameter clkdivider = 25000000/440/2;

    reg [14:0] counter;

  reg [7:0] reginput;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (reset) begin
        counter <= 0;
      end
      else begin
        if(counter==0) begin
          // change logic here (to add userinput)
            counter <= clkdivider-1; 
        end
        else begin
            counter <= counter-1;
        end
      end
    end

    reg speaker;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (reset) begin
        speaker <= 0;
      end
      else begin
        if(counter==0) begin
            speaker <= ~speaker;
        end
      end
    end

    // handshake
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
      reginput <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if (valid) begin
          reginput <= userinput;
        end
    end
  end

endmodule
```

You may want to compile the code here
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/PR2

Comment: Then dump the wave form to see your simulation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I still have some questions:

 1. Can you explain more what does the handshake do ? 
 2. I intend to have 12 frequencies that I will use for the musical notes, so I suppose I'll have an input of 4 bits to determine which frequency is played, and I want the counter to change to the desired frequency ( suppose for example input value 4'b0010 stands for frequency 390 Hz, so I want the clkdivider to change to 25000000/390/2, so that the counter would count to a different value. How do I do that ?

Comment: Should I add multiple paramters for each input such as :

parameter input0010 = 25000000/390/2; and then in the counter I'd have a case statement and I'd have counter <= input0010 - 1; when input is 0010, and likewise for each input ? or is there a neater way of doing it ?

Comment: 1. It's a one way handshake. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645541/verilog-two-way-handshaking-example) is an explanation for a two way handshake. The idea is still the same with one way handshake.

Comment: 2. This would be a long discussion. email on my profile to help you further.